# EF6 - Index creation strategy

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on an EF6 code first project that writes in a SQL Server database using a historical CRUD approach.

Therefore my tables have in common the following columns:

- `StartDate` and `EndDate`: this is the validity range of the record
- `GroupId`: is a column containing an int that is used in any query as the database has been created to contain multi-company data

Moreover, the column has a logical Id that is a Guid and represents the univocal way to recognize an entity and all its history.

The column contains also an identity that is the primary key, but is not used in the business logic.

Basically I have two kind of queries:

1. the first type is used to extract a list of entities, therefore it will be similar to this:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM CLASS 
   WHERE date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate 
     AND GroupId = N
   ```
2. the second type to extract the active record of a single entity:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM CLASS 
   WHERE GUID = 'myGuid' 
     AND date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate 
     AND GroupId = N
   ```

What kind of indexes should I create? Should it be better to create many single-column indexes or maybe two multi-column indexes (one with the dates and the `GroupId` and the other with the dates, `GroupId` and the Guid)?

Moreover, should I take some extra care writing LINQ queries, especially with the order of the conditions inside the query (to make sure the index is properly used)?

Comment: Write your Code-First Approach.  Write your EF queries.  Simulate real-world use as best as you can.  Internet search for "glenn berry dmv superhero" and you'll find some DMV queries that you can use....what will suggest the indexes you might add to your system.

Comment: Have a look at this one: it gives a very good overview on range indexes and what best to do in situations like yours: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates